# Docker images with visual(X) support? Or should I use VBox instead in this case?

Tags: docker, x11

I am totally new to Docker and have only, so far, used the images available on [Docker repos](https://registry.hub.docker.com/). 
I have already tested and being using docker for some aspects of my daily activities and it works great for me but in some specific cases I need a "virtual" image of Linux with graphic support(X in Ubuntu or CentOS) and so far I have only encountered on Docker repos images that by default don't have X support.
Should I in this case use a standard Virtual Box or VMWare image? Is it possible to run a visual version of Linux in a docker container? I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your containers in [privileged mode](http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration) they can access the host's resources (and to anything else for that matter), so in essence it is possible though I'd be willing to bet that it turns out to be more trouble than it's worth because the containers won't be quite as portable as ones that don't require such outside resources.

Comment: Thanks, so the bottom line is that I should use some other type of more traditional virtualization to have X support. VirtualBox, VMWare or KVM than.